# Store image in Core Data in swift

Tags: swift, core-data

i'm trying to save a local image in my app to the core data model. I have created the entity and created an attribute for the image. But when i run the app it crashes with this error, `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "image"; desired type = NSData; given type = UIImage; value = <UIImage:` My code to save image is,

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Saloon", in: context)
    let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    newUser.setValue(nameLbl.text, forKey: "name")
    newUser.setValue(addressLbl.text, forKey: "address")
    newUser.setValue(distanceLbl.text, forKey: "distance")
    newUser.setValue(rating.text, forKey: "rating")
    newUser.setValue(imageView.image, forKey: "image") as? UIImage
 do {
        try context.save()
        print("saved")
    } catch {
        print("Failed saving")
    }
```

This is how i'm fetching the image,

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Saloon")
    //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "age = %@", "12")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {

            print(data.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
            let image: Data = data.value(forKey: "image")! as! Data
            let decodedimage = UIImage(data: image)
            imageView2.image = decodedimage
            name2Lbl.text = data.value(forKey: "name") as? String
            address2Lbl.text = data.value(forKey: "address") as? String
            distance2Lbl.text = data.value(forKey: "distance") as? String
            rating2Lbl.text = data.value(forKey: "rating") as? String
        }

    } catch {

        print("Failed")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save a UIImage directly in Core Data. Instead, you’ll have to convert the image to `NSData` (as in “desired type = NSData” in your error message). Here’s a `UIImage` extension for that:

```
extension UIImage {
    func jpegData(withCompressionQuality quality: CGFloat) -> Data? {
        return autoreleasepool(invoking: {() -> Data? in
            return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, quality)
        })
    }
}
```

The `quality` is a value from 0.0 through 1.0 with the latter representing the maximum quality of the JPEG compressed image. The use of `autoreleasepool` helps avoid occasional memory leakage problems observed when using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

You can then save the image using this code:

```
if let imageData = imageView.image .jpegData(withCompressionQuality: 1.0) {
    newUser.setValue(imageData, forKey: "image")
}
```

BTW, you can also convert to PNG instead of JPEG which is lossless if this is what you need. Use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` instead of `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

Comment: it is showing two error,
Use of unresolved identifier 'withCompressionQuality'
Use of unresolved identifier 'jpegData'

Comment: @raheem: Yes, you’re more or less converting it from `NSData` into an `UIImage` which is exactly what you need to do. You simply forgot to perform the reverse step when writing. You should, however, avoid implicitly unwrapped optionals as they are prone to crashes.

Comment: @raheem: Sorry, I didn‘t include the `extension UIImage`line—please see my updated code.

Comment: i have written that but still this error is coming. @Tom E

Comment: @raheem: Please place the UIImage extension in a separate .swift file and make sure there’s no typo—then you cannot have an “unresolved identifier” error. Also, clean your project just to be sure.

Comment: let me try. @Tom E

Comment: Bro i'm still getting the same error , i have now place the extension in seprate swift file. @Tom E

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173062/discussion-between-tom-e-and-raheem).

Comment: i'm in discussion check it. @Tom E

Comment: NSValueTransformer for the win.

Answer (score 1):

Deferring from the previous answer, it is possible to store images in Core Data as UIImage. Although this is not considered to be good practice as Databases are not meant for storing files. We don't use core data to store the images directly instead we use the file path to where the image data is stored on your phone.

Anyways, the best method I found out while developing a side-project is demonstrated below

1. [Set the entity codeGen to Manual/None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZkal.png)
2. Select the attribute you want to be of Image type and choose [transformable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slVNG.png) as it's type
3. [Enter Custom class identifier as UIImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIXbu.png)
4. Go to editor and select [Create NSManagedObject Subclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT6l9.png)
5. The Process will create 2 swift files depending on the number of your entities(I only had 1 entity). Now, select the `<EntityName> + CoreDataProperties.swift` file and [import UIKit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYv6v.png)

If, on clicking [Jump to Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLuag.png) for the `@NSManaged public var <attributeName: UIImage?` you are able to land on the [UIImage definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oOAH.png) your work is done.

Perform actions on the entities just like you would and you will be able to fetch, save, edit the image attribute by down-casting `<EntityName>?.value(forKey: "<attributeName>") as? UIImage`.

I had to use the entity as `NSManagedObject` type and was for some reason not able to access the image directly from the created subclass.